# Using MSM & solspace user - members with same email address needed

Tags: email, multi-site-manager, member-details, solspace-user

i currently have several MSM sites in our EE install, our member database is synched (one way to us) with a partner with many thousands of members, which get access to one of our MSM sites, and are assigned automatically a member group.

We now find ourselves with some of the members of our partner that want some of our other services, **but there email address is already in our system** - giving access to that member group, giving those individual members different groups are not an option. And ideally i done want to ask them to supply a different email address, for the second account.

As these particular members are created and approved in house, and not through registration. the best solution i can think of is to create a second account with a dummy email address, then modify the email address to their second account to their actual address, *so it will now be in the database twice.*

Is there potentially any issue with this?

If not is there anything we need to look out for?

Using EE v2.5.3

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately unique email address is EE core requirement, you cannot override without modifying system files.

You may consider using some add-ons for advanced permissions management, such as [Member Categories](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/member-categories) or [MSM Member Group Switcher](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/msm-member-group-switcher)

Actually I think MSM Member Group Switcher might be the thing you're looking for, as it allows the user to be treated as part of one or another member group depending on what site he's logged in at.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, modifying sys files is just asking for touble. Thanks for highlighting the Group switcher, interesting, will give this a try in our next test build.